# SELECT a few rows out of MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need to select category ids from my sql database.
I have a variable `$product_id` and for each product id there are three rows in a table that i need to select using PHP.

If I do `"SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE product_id='$prodid'";` I only get the one on the top.

How can I select all three `category_id`s which contain the same `product_id`?

Comment: Are categories and products in different tables and you are trying to JOIN them?

Comment: please post the php code that you're using to execute the query and retrieve the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are using PHP's mysql functions, is this correct?  I am figuring that your query is actually returning all three rows but you aren't fetching all of them.

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE product_id='$prodid'";
 $r = mysql_query($sql, $conn); //where $conn is your connection

 $x = mysql_fetch_SOMETHING($r); //where something is array, assoc, object, etc.
```

The fetch function gives only one row at a time.  You say you need three so it needs to be executed three times.

```
 $x[0] = mysql_fetch_assoc($r);
 $x[1] = mysql_fetch_assoc($r);
 $x[2] = mysql_fetch_assoc($r);
```

OR this would be better

```
while($curRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) //this returns false when its out of rows, returns false
{
     $categoryIds[] = $curRow['category_id'];
}
```

If this doesn't do it then your query is actually returning only one row and we need to see your tables/fields and maybe sample data.

Comment: I use mysql_fetch_array and print_r ($array); to see its conent and only got the first row.I was thinking about a while loop just after i asked the question. I will try this when i wake up, I just came home from my night shift. I'l let you know. Thank you very much.

Comment: mysql_fetch_array doesn't give an array of your rows.  it gives one row at a time with each field numerically indexed.  you need the while loop.  mysql_fetch_assoc does the same thing except the indexes are named after the field's name.  either use assoc or you need to determine which numerical index is category_id (this is easy if you change query from SELECT * to SELECT category_id, then you know its $curRow[0])

Comment: ok glad you get it.  you might want to consider redesigning with a many to many table like some others suggested, but its good you got this worked out. read up on the functions for the future http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php

Answer (score 1):

SQL seems to be correct, but Why do you store product_id in categories table? if it's one-to-many relation it would be better to store only category_id in products table.

Comment: This table only consist of cat_id and prod_id and is used to assign products to categories. The component(Virtuemart) was just built that way, I dont know why.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL query is correct for what you want to do. It will select **all the records** in table_name with the field product_id = $prodid (not only 1 or 3 but any that matches the variable)

To select a few records you should use the [LIMIT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html) keyword

You should look inside your table structure and the variable $prodid to find problems.